# GeometricObject and circle class

Tags: java

Why can't I invoke these methods from the `GeometricObject` class?

```
public abstract class GeometricObject {
    private String color = "white";
    private boolean filled;
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;

    /** Construct a default geometric object */
    protected GeometricObject() {
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    }

    /** Construct a geometric object with color and filled value */
    protected GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    /** Return color */
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    /** Set a new color */
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    /** Return filled. Since filled is boolean,
    *  the get method is named isFilled */
    public boolean isFilled() {
        return filled;
    }

    /** Set a new filled */
    public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    /** Get dateCreated */
    public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "created on " + dateCreated + "\ncolor: " + color +
            " and filled: " + filled;
    }

    /** Abstract method getArea */
    public abstract double getArea();

    /** Abstract method getPerimeter */
    public abstract double getPerimeter();
}
```

Comment: Don't post links. Post all relevant information here with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean why can't you invoke the `getArea()` and `getPerimeter()` methods, it is because they are abstract.

You cannot invoke an abstract method.  An abstract method must have an implementation in a concrete class.

Also, you cannot instantiate an interface or an abstract class. You can only instantiate concrete classes (and they may implement an interface or extend an abstract class).

So to use the `getArea()` and `getPerimeter()` methods, you need a concrete class that implements them.  Such as class might look something like this:

```
public class ConcreteGeometricObject extends GeometricObject {

    public ConcreteGeometricObject() {
        super();
    }

    public ConcreteGeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
        super(color, filled);
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        double area;
        //implementation code here
        return area;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        double perimeter;
        //implementation code here
        return perimeter;
    }
}
```

And you could use it in manner such as this:

```
GeometricObject geometricObject = new ConcreteGeometricObject();
//...
double area = geometricObject.getArea();
double perimeter = geometricObject.getPerimeter()
```

Please read this trail: [Lesson: Interfaces and Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html)